Duda con nodemailer usando el smtp de gmail
Cree un backend que solo recibe un post para enviar mails con nodemailer, lo arme en node.js con express.
En desarrollo va todo perfecto, se mandan el asunto, el mensaje y los archivos que se lleguen a adjuntar. Lo deploye en vercel, para probar como iba en un server y tira errores tras errores.
Como este :
Unhandled Rejection: Error: Connection timeout
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:798:19)
at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:20)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:237:22)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
command: 'CONN'
}

La idea es un formulario de contacto, en donde cargas un asunto y un mensaje, el usuario se toma por el que se loguea en la pagina, y el destinatario es hardcode por el momento.
Necesito saber:

si es posible usar el smtp de gmail en producción

si es posible que solución se le puede ver


si no de que otra manera puedo realizar envíos de mails.

Intentos
ya intente variar puertos y deshabilitar el secure del createTransport en el nodemailer y no pasa nada, sigue surgiendo error

Diria que estos de Vercel estan bloqueando el puerto 25 del SMTP de salida por defecto, tal como parecen contar aqui: https://vercel.com/guides/serverless-functions-and-smtp
